# Plotting 2D map coordinates to OpenGL 3D projection

Tags: opengl, c++, mathematics

I’m trying to convert a 2D map created in my map editor to a 3D plotting with OpenGL. This is my map generated in my map editor:

[image: Map editor]

Those vertices are relative to my Cartesian origin world coordinate (top up of the picture) and I’m applying this formula to convert it to an OpenGL object coordinate:

World size: 800x600

```
x = (X / 800) -0.5
y = (Y / 600) -0.5
```

Getting this result:

(First object face)

```
−0.48625, 0.068333333
0.12625, 0.07
0.12875, −0.481666667
−0.4875, −0.486666667
```

Plotting this vertex buffer in OpenGL, I got a very weird result. So how can I get a 3D model from those vertex positions? Like this picture:

[image: Box room]

I’m rendering OpenGL in triangles mode and using this example as the start point: https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/blob/master/src/1.getting_started/7.4.camera_class/camera_class.cpp

**Edit:**

Using the conversion formula + the Earcut tessellation (https://github.com/mapbox/earcut.hpp), I've finally got this rectangle rendering correctly inside OpenGL. With two planes with just the Z-axis different, now the problem is how to render its laterals since Earcut just works with 2D coordinates...

[image: Planes]